# pdnsutil - preventing duplicate DNS record creation

Tags: powerdns

If you use **pdnsutil add-record** it permits duplicate dns entries to be created. Is there some way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cheated (a bit) on this one. I need a way to map my forward zone to a reverse zone and run it via script.

My setup uses **mysql** as the back end so I changed the **records** table as follows:

`alter table records add constraint dom_type_co unique (domain_id, type, content);`

Now if I try to create a duplicate record I get an error msg:

> Error: GSQLBackend unable to feed record: Could not execute mysql statement ...

---

As an aside - to map a forward zone to a reverse:

`pdnsutil list-zone mydom | grep "10\.95\.96"  |  awk '{ printf "%s %s\n",$5,$1 }' | cut -c 10- | xargs -L 1 pdnsutil add-record 96.95.10.in-addr.arpa $1 PTR $2`

Obviously you'll need to change it to fit your IP address/length.